# Create Magento Configuration Dynamic Field like the one here http://mustakarhu.com/blog/dynamic-input-field-in-magento-admin-configuration/

Tags: magento

I need to create a dynamic config field for magento module like the one explained here http://mustakarhu.com/blog/dynamic-input-field-in-magento-admin-configuration/.

The article is good but very brief i could not make that work, can anybody provide me some working example or point me to right direction may be another article with detailed explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: What part doesn't work? The rendering or saving/loading the data?